# Reading a single byte using 3 wire interface

Tags: pic, spi, rtc

I am trying to communicate with [DS1302](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1302.pdf) (RTC) using [P16f877A](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41417B.pdf) MCU. I tried to read a single register (let say Hour-register) of DS1302 and put its value on a certain PORT/LCD. But I am doing something wrong because **everytime i get the same value i.e. 0x01 when I read either date,hour,minutes or seconds** etc.

Here is how i am doing to read the byte from RTC.

```
sbit EN at PORTC.B2;
sbit SCLK at PORTC.B3;
sbit SDI at PORTC.B4;
sbit SDO at PORTC.B5;

sbit EN_Direction at TRISC2_bit;
sbit SCLK_Direction at TRISC3_bit;
sbit SDI_Direction at TRISC4_bit;
sbit SDO_Direction at TRISC5_bit;

// SPI Initialization Fucntion

void SPI_init(void){

          INTCON |= 0xC0;     // GIE and PEIE enable
          SSPSTAT.SMP = 0;    // Sample at MIDDLE
          SSPSTAT.CKE = 1;    // Data send on Rising Edge
          SSPCON |= 0x21;    // Serial Port Enable, Idle state Clk is Low, Clock = Fosc/16 => 31 KBytes/sec
          SCLK_Direction=0;
          SDO_Direction =0;
          EN_Direction  =0;      // Output Ports
          SDI_Direction =1;
          EN  =   1;                
}

// ============== Main function =============

void main(){

           SPI_init();
           EN=0;                       // Active low signal
           SSPBUF = 0x85;         // Hour Address
           while(SSPSTAT.BF == 0);     // Adress Transmission not complete ? Stay here
           value=SSPBUF;               // Read to Clear BufferFullStatusBit
           while(SSPSTAT.BF == 0);     // Recieve byte not complete ? Stay here
           value=SSPBUF;               // Store the recieved Byte
           EN=1;                       // Fininsh Reading
           PORTB=value;                // Transfer byte to PORTB
}
```

The timing diagram of RTC is as follows

[image]

Comment: Timing diagram states that CE (this is the Enable signal IMO) should be held high for proper data communications. But you hold it low during data communications. One more thing: 85h has 1 in its most significant bit and this means READ for the chip. So, writing 85h cannot initiate a register write action for it.

Comment: The CE pin (in the schematic of proteus) is shown below. It is active low therefor I used EN=0 at the start of communication
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16158781/qw.PNG 

In the datasheet, it is stated that " the LSB (bit 0) specifies a write operation (input) if logic 0 or read operation (output) if logic 1" So 85H has MSB and LSB both set high. Kindly view the below table of the datasheet. Below is the ScreenShot
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16158781/Capture.PNG

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been abandoned by the asked for years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions.

1. Use software SPI and change the data direction.
2. Use a resistor to isolate the miso and mosi lines. Miso to sdio directly and mosi to sdio via a resistor.

Notice also CE is active high.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest read seconds register and check if BIT-7 is 1[CH].
If its 1[CH] you will need to clear it, to make DS1302 ticking.
Look in the datasheet for "CLOCK HALT FLAG".